# Change branch-off point

Tags: git

I have a branch called `feature` and it has a few commits.  The branch and its commits are still local to my machine (haven't been `push`ed to a public repository).  The graph looks like

```
A---B---C---D---E---F---G master
                    \
                     P---Q---R feature
```

Now I realized that I should've made the branch `feature` off of an earlier commit on `master`.  Let's say commit `C`.  In other words, the graph *should* look like

```
A---B---C---D---E---F---G master
         \
          P---Q---R feature
```

What I am trying to do in essence is revert commits `D`, `E` and `F` out of the `feature` branch.  Yes, I could just `revert` commits one at a time but there are too many to revert; the above picture is just an illustration.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you want to do is a *rebase*. To pick up the commits `P`, `Q` and `R` and apply them on top of `C`, you execute:

```
git rebase --onto C F feature
```

See the man-page of `git-rebase` for more information.

Comment: Perfect.  Turns out I didn't read _far enough_ into the man page.  I _did do_ a `rebase` before posting the question.  However that just said that `commit C` already existed.  The secret sauce is the `--onto` switch.  Thanks