# Change branch base

Tags: git

I've a tree like this:

```
(commit 1) - master
                \-- (commit 2) - (commit 3) - demo
                                                \-- (commit 4) - (commit 5) - PRO
```

and I have to move the PRO branch to master

```
(commit 1) - master
                |-- (commit 2) - (commit 3) - demo
                \-- (commit 4) - (commit 5) - PRO
```

I've tried a `git rebase master` from PRO branch, but nothing happens.

**To clarify**: I was working in master and then I had to make a product demo (`git checkout -b demo` and some commits). Then, by mistake, I create another branch from demo (`git checkout -b PRO` and some commits) and now I need to move PRO branch to master and leave demo intact. At the end, both demo and PRO will hang from master.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change branch-off point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803069/change-branch-off-point)

Answer (score 664, accepted):

Assuming `newBase` is the branch you want to move your commits onto, `oldBase` is the old basis for your branch, you can use [`--onto`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#git-rebase---ontoltnewbasegt) for that:

```
git rebase --onto newBase oldBase feature/branch
```

Given your case:

```
git checkout PRO # Just to be clear which branch to be on.
git rebase --onto master demo PRO
```

Basically, you take all the commits from after `demo` up to and including `PRO`, and rebase them onto the `master` commit.

Comment: Is that also the way to go if the situation is the opposite? == I checkout -b from master the second branch, but I wanted to do it from the first one. So I did `git rebase --onto first-branch second-branch second-branch` but I don't get the syntax

Comment: @Fla in that case, it would be `git rebase --onto first-branch master second-branch`

Comment: I read this [guide](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase) on `--onto`, and how they wrote helped me `git rebase --onto newBase oldBase feature/branch`

Comment: @PhilipRego That is incorrect. `origin/newBase` is the name of a branch, just like `newBase` in my example. It would just depend if you are rebasing onto a branch that exists in your local repository (`newBase`), or one that exists on the remote (`origin/newBase`).

Comment: @PhilipRego Those aren't independent things. `newBase` is the name of a local branch, and `origin/newBase` is the name of a remote branch. Which one you want depends on what you're rebasing onto. It's not that one works and one doesn't, it is that they rebase onto different things. The original question never mentions remotes, so using remotes in my example would not match the question that was asked.

Comment: Please ask a new question. Posting examples like this in comments is not productive. I never said to run `git fetch` and clearly there is a misunderstanding here that can't be resolved in a comment.

Comment: This did not work for me. At first, I wasn't too sure why. But a little later I noticed that my `master` branch was not up to date when I tried the rebase. So for those who are trying to do such, I suggest you first go to master (`git checkout master`) do a pull, fix any potential problem (`git pull origin master`), then go back to your branch and try to rebase again (last two lines from loganfsmyth).

Comment: So it _remotely looks_ like the `--onto` works, but when I do `git status`, it still tells me that I'm ahead by N commits of `oldBase`. Why is that? If I ask git to `rebase --onto master ...`, should the status then tell me I'm ahead by N commits of `master`?!

Comment: Love the description, "after `...` up to `...`, and rebase them onto `...` commit".

Comment: I am getting -> fatal: does not point to a valid commit '[newBase]'

Comment: @Harshil `newBase` is a placeholder. It would be whatever your local change name is.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Yes I get that. I tried with my new base branch only. Anyway I updated base branch from github PR directly. Solved. thanks

Comment: Note that `oldBase` can be a commit hash. This may be useful if, like me, you've already deleted the `demo` branch.

Answer (score 63):

I will try to be as generic as I can be. First, be sure that you are on the desired branch:

```
git checkout current-branch
```

Then use the following command (where `new-base-branch` is the branch which you want to be your new base, and `current-base-branch` is the branch which is your current base.)

```
git rebase --onto new-base-branch current-base-branch
```

**If you do not have conflicts, then great - you are done. If you do (in most cases), then please read on.**

Conflicts might arise, and you will have to resolve them manually. Git now tries to do a "3-way merge" between your `current-branch`, `current-base-branch` and `new-base-branch`.   Roughly this is how git will work internally:

1. Git will first rebase the `current-base-branch` on top of the `new-base-branch`. There might be conflicts; which you will have to resolve manually. After that is done, you usually do `git add .` and `git rebase --continue`. It will create a new temporary commit `temp-commit-hash` for this.
2. After this, Git will now rebase your `current-branch` on top of `temp-commit-hash`. There might be further conflicts and again you will have to resolve them manually. Once done, you continue again with `git add .` and `git rebase --continue`, after which you have successfully rebased your `current-branch` on top the `new-base-branch`.

---

**Note:** If you start to mess up, then you can do `git rebase --abort` anytime during the rebase process and get back to the starting point.

Comment: The `rebase` command as posted just gives me "fatal: invalid upstream 'current-base-branch'".  Also, why is it even necessary to tell GIT what the current parent branch of the current branch is - shouldn't it know this already?

Comment: @ARK simple explanation. Thank you. Worked for me.

Comment: At the end, remember not to pull from origin but only force push to origin

Answer (score 43):

Checkout to `PRO` branch, Copy the oldest (*commit4*) and latest (*commit5*) commit hashes of this branch and paste somewhere else:

```
$ git checkout PRO
$ git log            # see the commit history
# copy the oldest & latest commit-hash
```

Delete the `PRO` branch (keep a backup just for safety). Create and checkout to a new `PRO` branch from `master`:

```
$ git branch PRO.bac    # create a new branch PRO.bac = PRO as backup

$ git checkout master
$ git branch -D PRO     # delete the local PRO branch
$ git checkout -b PRO   # create and checkout to a new 'PRO' branch from 'master'
```

Take (*cherry-pick*) the range of commits of Previous `PRO` branch into the new `PRO` branch:

```
$ git cherry-pick commit4^..commit5   # cherry-pick range of commits
# note the '^' after commit4
```

Now, if all is ok, then do force (-f) push to `remote PRO` branch and delete local `PRO.bac` branch:

```
$ git log                  # check the commit history

$ git push -f origin HEAD  # replace the remote PRO by local PRO branch history
# git branch -D PRO.bac    # delete local PRO.bac branch
```

Comment: Note that you should update your code, to make a backup and delete the original, you can instead do: `git branch -m PRO PRO.bac` — a simple rename of the branch.

Answer (score 4):

I had a slightly different approach using reset and stashes that avoids deleting and re-creating branches as well as eliminating the need to switch branches:

```
$ git checkout PRO
$ git reset commit4 # This will set PROs HEAD to be at commit 4, and leave the modified commit 5 files in ur working index
$ git stash save -m "Commit message"
$ git reset commit3
$ git stash save -m "Commit message"
$ git reset master --hard
$ git stash pop
$ git stash pop
$ git push --force # force if its already been push remotely
```

By resetting the branch on a commit-by-commit basis your basically just rewinding that branches history a commit at a time.

Comment: Should you remove the space between "commit" and "3" on the 4th line?

Answer (score 0):

Another option not mentioned yet would be to use **interactive rebase** where you can simply mark `commit 2 & commit 3` to be removed and only keep `commit 1 & commit 4 & commit 5`.

```
# Run interactive rebase
git rebase -i HEAD^5

# rebase options will get displayed in text editor
pick a89b78c Commit1
pick b136d0a Commit2
pick c231e8d Commit3
pick d54274b Commit4
pick e87218e Commit5

# keep lines with commits you want in branch and save file
pick a89b78c Commit1
pick d54274b Commit4
pick e87218e Commit5
```

Answer (score -11):

```
git branch --set-upstream-to another_branch
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. Please check the commit graph in the question, where it was asking how to move the branch `PRO` so that it is branched-off from an older `master` branch instead of from `demo`. This command just changes the remote branch.

Comment: This devastated my environment as I was in a hurry. Why is it appearing as the first response?