# How to change base branch in git?

Tags: git

Problem is described in the image as it was giving some error in the text.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Solving support questions on SO. That's a new for me.

Comment: If you have not done any work in child1 child2 delete them and recreate as you meant to create. If work is done create temp(backup) branches out of child1 and child2 delete them and create as you meant and cherry pick from temp(backup) branches.

Comment: Answer is given here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/10853956/4741746

Answer (score 12):

I don't know why your question is being downvoted, because it's legitimate and very much a common mistake that beginner users make when using Git.

You accidentally created branch `BR-02` from branch `BR-01`.  One solution is to create a branch using the correct base, and then cherry-pick any commits you have made on `BR-02` onto this correct branch.

```
git checkout BS-00      # switch to the correct branch
git checkout -b BR-03   # create the correct branch using BS-00 as a base
git cherry-pick <SHA-1> # cherry-pick the commit from BR-02
```

Here `<SHA-1>` is the hash of the commit on branch `BR-02` which you wish to keep.  You can find out this value by switching to `BR-02` and typing `git log` from the terminal.

Note that this is effectively merging the commit you made on branch `BR-02` into the branch `BR-03`, so there might be conflicts.  Finally, you can delete the bad branch `BR-02` since you don't need it anymore:

```
git branch -d BR-02     # delete the wrong branch BR-02 locally
git push origin :BR-02  # delete the wrong branch BR-02 on the remote
```

Comment: I did commit a file in this branch and git push origin on this branch.
@Tim Biegeleisen could you please elaborate this case a bit.

Comment: I updated my answer.  You need to create a correct branch, and then cherry-pick the good commit you made onto the branch `BR-02`.

Comment: I am not supposed to delete any created branch, is there any option to rebase it to BS-00? I mean how will rebase work in this case?

Comment: There are all sorts of problems with rebasing for you.  First, you will have to do an interactive rebase to remove any commits which did not exist on `BR-00` which you don't want.  Second, you will be rewriting history, which means anyone else who pulls the branch after rebasing could have problems.  I vote for creating a new branch and cherry-picking what you want, though others may disagree with me.