# How to move starting point of branch to an older commit

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit, git-history

I'd like to rebase my branch onto an older commit to exclude code added by the newer commits.

What I have:

```
A---B---C---D---E master
                 \
                  F---G---H---I---J experiment
```

What I want:

```
A---B---C---D---E master
     \
      F---G---H---I---J experiment
```

Say I wanted to make my `experiment` branch on commit `B`, but didn't realize I made it on `E`. By the time I realize, I already made a bunch of commits and they include code changes I don't want (`C`, `D`, `E`).

How do I move the starting point of `experiment` to the older commit `B`?

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38427050/how-to-change-the-starting-point-of-a-branch) but haven't seen anything usable regarding moving the branch to an older commit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change branch base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853935/change-branch-base)

Comment: Note that the "starting point" of branch `experiment` is, and remains, commit `A`. What you do when you rebase it (see [eftshift0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68400773/1256452)) is *copy* commits `F-G-H-I-J` to new and improved, different commits `F'-G'-H'-I'-J'` where `F'` builds on `B` instead of `E`, `G'` builds on `F'` instead of `F`, and so on.

Comment: Commits `A-B-C-D-E` are currently on *both branches* and after you're done, `A-B` will be on both branches with `C-D-E` exclusively on one and `F'-...-J'` exclusively on the other. Branches therefore don't (usefully) have *starting points*, they only have *ending points*. That's why you have to do things like `git log B..experiment` or `git log master..experiment` to limit what `git log` shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

```
git rebase --onto B master experiment
```

That command is read like this: `git rebase --onto new-base discard-revisions-in-this-history this-is-what-i-want-to-rebase`.

Git actually doesn't mind if the base is newer or older than where you are (simple example that might be rather common: a **backport**). It's all about the changes that are introduced that are in each revision that will be rebased.

Comment: Thank you! After reviewing your answer and the others spotted by SO, and reading `man git rebase` more thoroughly, it seems a more accurate interpretation is `git rebase --onto commit range-start-non-inclusive range-end-inclusive`.

Comment: Well, perhaps, it depends on how you understand the concept... and as long as it is clear, I have no objection. The only thing about what you call `range-start-non-inclusive` is that it can be a spot different from `E` in your example. Suppose that master has another revision on top of E, say `K` (`experiment` diverging from E, no change). There, you could still use `master` (pointing to `K`) as `range-start-non-inclusive`. That's why I read it as `discard-revisions-in-this-history`.

Comment: Very interesting point! I have to digest that further.

Comment: Sure. When I said `understand`, I meant `visualize`. I am sure you understood already.