# Rebasing or merging in IntelliJ Idea 2022

Tags: git, intellij-idea, merge, branch, rebase

I haven't used Git in a very long time, and I'm in the process of learning more about it, but I have to do something through IntelliJ Idea 2022 that I've never done before, and despite my best efforts of research I can't figure out how to do this properly. I would mess around with this myself a lot more if it wouldn't affect other people, but I could mess up quite a few people's days pretty bad if I do the wrong thing here, so I wanted to make sure I was doing the right thing before I tried anything more than research.

I created a project in IntelliJ Idea 2022 from a remote repository, compiled it, no issues there. I then created a named branch called "branch1" (not the real name, for illustration) and pushed that branch to the remote repository by choosing "Git -> Push" in IntelliJ and confirmed that the branch was there in the remote repository so I could update it later.

However, I accidentally made branch1 from the "master" branch, and I was supposed to make it from the "develop" branch. In the lower right hand corner of IntelliJ I can click on the "branch1" name, and navigate down to "origin/develop," but it's there that I'm getting confused.

I want my "branch1" to act as though I took it out of "origin/develop" to start with, but I have a lot of options on the context menu for "origin/develop", and I'm not sure which one to pick.

I have:

```
Checkout
New Branch from "origin/develop"
Checkout and Rebase onto "branch1"
Compare with "branch1"
Show Diff with Working Tree
Rebase "branch1" onto "origin/develop"
Merge "origin/develop" into "branch1"
Pull into "branch1" using Rebase
Pull into "branch1" using Merge
Delete
```

Right off the bat, I know I don't want to delete "origin/develop," and I don't need to compare branches or show diffs, so those options are out. I also understand after my research that I should have just done the "New Branch from orgin/develop" option; I'll know to do that for next time. The options giving me confusion at this point are:

```
Checkout
Checkout and Rebase onto "branch1"
Rebase "branch1" onto "origin/develop"
Merge "origin/develop" into "branch1"
Pull into "branch1" using Rebase
Pull into "branch1" using Merge
```

I don't think I have to check out "origin/develop" to fix this but I'm not sure about that because the "Checkout and Rebase" option exists. I'm supposed to keep my created branch name the same, and I was told not to delete the branch I already made.

The rest of the rebase/merge options, I'm just not sure which one to pick (if I should pick them at all) because I'm not sure which direction/action is the right one.

Can anyone give me some guidance on this, please? Thanks!

Comment: If your remote happens to be GitHub, I think you can create a PR and change its "base" branch in the GitHub UI. That may be the easiest way. Otherwise you're probably better off on the command line. Git will need a little bit of convincing to do what you describe. It effectively changes the history, which in the general sense can be destructive. In practice that will involve a `git reset` and `git push --force`.

Comment: @KnutForkalsrud Thank you! I don't really know how to use the UI; the only thing I have in that UI is a tiny little dialog with a link to create a new repository or open a repository. I know even less about the GitHub UI than IntelliJ; that's why I was hoping to keep things in IntelliJ and learn as I went. Since you're talking about 2 commands here, though, does that mean IntelliJ can't do what I'm hoping for?

Comment: Not sure, I have never done this kind of thing in IntelliJ.

Comment: @jsrc..programmer

You may find this thread useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853935/change-branch-base

But overall, you can checkout your branch1, then click on `develop` branch and choose "Rebase `branch1` onto `develop`"

Answer (score 0):

You want »Rebase "branch1" onto "origin/develop"«. But you do not want to rebase all commits that are not in develop, but only the ones that are reachable from "branch1", but not from "master". On the command line you would use the `--onto` option or an interactive rebase.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you *have to* do this with IntelliJ? Simply do it via the command line, it's a lot simpler and the commands do exactly what they are supposed to do.

```
git rebase --onto origin/develop origin/master branch1
```

This will:

- Check out "branch1"
- Copy all commits between `origin/master` and `branch1`
- Re-create them as new commits on top of `origin/develop`

Afterwards, you can force-push your updated branch to the remote repository to pretend your mistake never happened.